# What's wrong with my Apache CXF client?

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws, cxf

This is part of my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
  <version>${cxf.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
  <version>${cxf.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I'm trying to use Apache CXF as an implementation of JAX-WS. Everything works fine (Java code is generated from WSDL by means of `org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.4.0`), until execution:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
javax.wsdl.xml.WSDLReader.readWSDL(Ljavax/wsdl/xml/WSDLLocator;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)Ljavax/wsdl/Definition;
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:237)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:91)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:203)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:147)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:90)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
....
```

What is it about? What dependency did I miss?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You likely have a 1.5 (or older) version of wsdl4j coming from someplace else.   CXF requires the 1.6.x versions.

**EDIT:**

Also be on the lookout for the Axis version of this jar. You can exclude it like so:

```
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>axis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

Comment: I had a legacy WS using Axis mixed in causing grief, add to it that the axis version has "axis" appended to the group id :( - thanks for this +1

Answer (score 2):

This dependency is wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar, it probably does not get transitively resolved with the current set of dependencies you have.