# Class loading issue involving CXF on Websphere, parent last not helping

Tags: websphere, cxf, nosuchmethoderror

My problem concerns CXF and the wsdl4j_1.6.2.jar colliding with something, presumably the axis-wsdl4j.jar.

I have read: [What's wrong with my Apache CXF client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066054/whats-wrong-with-my-apache-cxf-client)

My project does not include the axis-wsdl4j.jar in the war. I have also asked our admin to switch Websphere to Parent Last. I still get this:

> [12/13/12 16:01:28:378 CST] 0000001b ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E:
>   Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the
>   servlet: CXFServlet. Exceptio n thrown : java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault:
>   javax/wsdl/xml/WSDLReader.readWSDL(Ljavax/wsdl/xml/WSDLLocator;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)
>   Ljavax/wsdl/Definition;
>           at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
>           at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:322)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:122)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:211)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:213)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:154)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:129)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:187)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:110)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:166)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1143)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:591)
>           at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3453)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:267)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:815)
>           at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1466)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:119)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473) Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault:
>   javax/wsdl/xml/WSDLReader.readWSDL(Ljavax/wsdl/xml/WSDLLocator;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)Ljavax/wsdl/Definition;
>           at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
>           at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
>           at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:167)
>           at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:94)
>           at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
>           at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
>           at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
>           ... 26 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/wsdl/xml/WSDLReader.readWSDL(Ljavax/wsdl/xml/WSDLLocator;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)Ljavax/wsdl/Definition;
>           at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:242)
>           at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
>           at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
>           at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:203)
>           at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.(ServiceImpl.java:147)
>           at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:97)
>           at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:35)
>          ...

Project is built by Maven, deployed to Websphere via Continuum only; and all settings are changed via request. Application runs perfect on local Tomcat.

EDIT:
This was eventually fixed by:

1. Copy wsdl4j.jar to /usr/WebSphere/AppServer/appLibs/APPNAME directory.
2. Chmod 775 on previous.
3. In websphere admin console, environment (on left), Shared Libraries, and define a container wide shared library with name as APPNAME above.
4. Add the jar to the classpath of the shared library.
5. Servers (on left), APPNAME java, process management, Class Loader and make sure "Classes loaded with application class loader first"
6. Click on the class loader and assign the shared library to it.
7. Restart Server

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to disable Jax ws engine

Try setting JVM property as below

```
com.ibm.websphere.webservices.DisableIBMJAXWSEngine=true
```

Comment: I did try adding: `DisableIBMJAXWSEngine: true` to Manifest.MF but it had no affect. I will try that next.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i would do.

Turn on verbose class loading on WAS runtime and look at the JAR that contains WSDLReader.

Check if this is the JAR that you expected to be used in run-time (to start with) based on the verbose class loading.

HTH

Comment: I assume you mean passing `-Dibm.cl.verbose=ClassToTrace WSDLReader` to the jvm?